# How to remove leading spaces in float numbers

Tags: regex

[snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfSzD.png)Thanks all for the answers. This is the exp that worked
twt_clean.text.str.extract('((.(?=\d+)[0-9]*.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/([1-9][0-9]+))')

**Output:**

```
12/10        486
10/10        436
11/10        413
13/10        287
9/10         153
8/10          98
7/10          51
14/10         38
5/10          33
6/10          32
3/10          19
4/10          15
2/10           9
1/10           4
204/170        1
80/80          1
9/11           1
 11.26/10      1
88/80          1
50/50          1
4/20           1
7/11           1
144/120        1
44/40          1
420/10         1
0/10           1
45/50          1
84/70          1
1776/10        1
 13.5/10       1
165/150        1
99/90          1
60/50          1
121/110        1
 11.27/10      1
 9.75/10       1
Name: ratings, dtype: int64
```

But now, the result of the above exp fetches leading spaces in few rows which are not integers but floats. Within the above exp itself how to eliminate the leading spaces. Please help.

Comment: `((\d+\.\d+|\d+)/([1-9]\d+))` https://regex101.com/r/l6Kapl/1

Comment: Try matching a space or a tab before and then use a capturing group `[ \t]*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?/[1-9]\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/e1nqEa/1

Comment: @Pauline Was my answer helpful?

Comment: Does `([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)/([1-9][0-9]+)` work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that extra space due to the dot followed by the positive lookahead `.(?=\d+)` which asserts what is on the right is 1+ digits.

Note that the dot matches any character except a newline and you have to escape the dot match it literally `\.`

If you don't use the capturing groups any further in your code or tool, you might omit them and use non capturing groups `(?:` instead.

You could update your expression to:

```
(?:[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+)/[1-9][0-9]+
```

That will match:

- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `[0-9]*\.[0-9]+` Match 0+ times a digit, a dot and 1+ times a digit
  - `|` Or
  - `[0-9]+` Match 1+ times a digit
- `)` Close non capturing group
- `/` Match forward slash
- `[1-9][0-9]+` Match a digit 1-9 followed by matching 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cVAoML/1)